# Putty doesn't work beyond proxy

Tags: proxy, putty

I can browse the internet by setting up Firefox to use a proxy server on port 8080 with need of authentication. It seems that everything else is blocked by the proxy server. For example, in command prompt even ping 4.2.2.4 doesn't pong. In such a network i need to use putty to access my server.
is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

A proxy on port 8080 is likely to be an application specific proxy. in this case, an HTTP proxy.

Other types of proxies (e.g. "Socks" proxies) are more general purpose but are configured differently in the client.

Often, a local network firewall is configured in conjunction with the proxy so that any traffic not passing through the proxy is blocked - i.e cannot contact external servers. If this is the case, you have few options.

- Ask the proxy and/or firewall administrator to allow you to use SSH from inside the network to access specified external servers.
- Tunnel SSH through HTTP ([example](http://dag.wiee.rs/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/)).

Comment: thanks for the link. i went to rate it as useful, but unfortunately couldn't because of my reputations. now i'm going to read the document and will mark it as an answer if it will solve the problem. i really know nothing or very little about networking.

Comment: it's a bit hard for me to understand. besides, i may access my server via browser (http://<ip>). for configuring my server, i need to ssh to my server which is impossible at work. with the current config of my server, how can i connect with any protocol like ssh, telnet, secure shell, etc. to my server? if it's impossible, i've to go home, edit some config files, restart some services and come back to work and see whether it works, which is practically impossible. isn't there a client/server solution or something?

Comment: @hamid, then reconfigure the firewall.

Comment: it's beyond of my control

Comment: @hamid. Then use your smartphone or personal tablet's data plan. E.g. using connectbot SSH client. Or use something like webmin.

Comment: how can i connect the LAN's internet to mobile data? may i force it to be routed via mobile?